# How to add a form xtype sencha touch 2.0

Tags: panel, sencha-touch-2

Currently I am teaching myself Sencha Touch 2.0 and I am encountering a problem with adding a xtype called test to my viewport.

The test class is extending "Ext.form.Panel'" the problem is that no form shows up in my view and sencha also doesn't give any errors. When I extend "Ext.Panel" and set a html attribute this does show up. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong ?

**Viewport file**

```
Ext.define('App.view.Viewport', {
extend: 'Ext.viewport.Default',



config: {

    scrollable: true,
    fullscreen:true,
    items:[
        {
            xtype: "panel",
            items: [
                {
                    xtype:"toolbar",
                    title:"Test App"
                },
                {
                    xtype:"panel",
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype:"test"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

});

**Controller file**

```
   //Define controller name 
Ext.define('App.controller.User', {
    //Extend the controller class
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    //define associated views with this controller
    views: ['user.Test'],


    init: function()
    {
        //do something and setup listeners

        //setup listeners 

    }


});
```

**View File**

```
Ext.define('App.view.user.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.test',



    config: {
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'name',
            label: 'Name'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'emailfield',
            name: 'email',
            label: 'Email'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'passwordfield',
            name: 'password',
            label: 'Password'
        }
    ]
    },
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('initialize home view');
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify

```
xtype: 'test'
```

in your `App.view.user.Test` definition

Comment: this is the same as alias: "widget.Test". Though when i do this i get a blank screen, i tried extending it from a normal panel and then i DO see my input fields.

Comment: try to do not wrap your FormPanel into Panel unless there is a good reason for that

Answer (score 0):

I have got it sorted. Have a look at:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?191765-My-Ext.form.Panel-object-does-not-want-to-show&p=767689#post767689